# Drive API Upload throws error "Invalid credentials"

Tags: c#

I am trying to upload large files size more than 1 GB to Google drive using Drive API(Implemented in c#). I created a service account to upload the files. The application working fine for an hour and throwing error "Invalid Credentials" after that.

I read some other posts from internet which is saying that is is an issue in server side. There is no need to change the client code.

I have to upload larger files without any issues. How can I overcome this issue?